# Restrict website access to specific location

Tags: geolocation, web, ip, restriction

I am working on a personal website that I would like only accessible to people in my town. I was thinking of somehow using the IP address of the person accessing the site or having them verify their address but that seems too complex. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: There are ways to map IP addresses to physical locations, but even then there is the possibility that someone could still access your site through a proxy server.